# How to go to an anchor on scroll in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to add an effect on a page that I'm working on. On it there's a cover with a fixed image and after there's a container. What I'd like to do would be to have the page scrolling with the fixed image just when the user scrolls with his mouse.

I thought something really simple like that, since it works when I put `onclick` and not `onscroll` but of course it doesn't work:

```
<div class="cover" onscroll="window.location = '#container';">
    ...
</div>

<div class="container" id="container">
    ...
</div>
```

Basically I'd like something like that, but with the image staying at the same place and the same size: https://tympanus.net/Development/ArticleIntroEffects/

Someone has a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure if I get you, but I think CSS scroll snap is something that's potentially interesting (check compatibility though).

Comment: `onscroll` runs when content within the element scrolls, so unless there is content inside of that `div`, that will never get called. It's a bit confusing what you want. It sounds like you just want to have a fixed background image (since you want it to stay "in the same place and the same size"), but then you show this completely different effect...

Comment: Yes I'm showing something a bit different because it was the closest animation I found... But yes I just would like to have the background with a fixed position. Inside the div there's some content (a `<img>` tag)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is `Element.scrollTo`([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo)) just like this:

```
let container = document.getElementById('container');
document.onwheel = function(e) {
  document.body.parentNode.scrollTo({
    top: container.offsetTop,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};
```

It scrolls your `<html>` element so your #container would be on top of the screen

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it scrolls the page on load and not on scroll. How could I do that? (Sorry I'm really bad in JS...)

Comment: With your link I tried something like that:
```
function scrollCover() {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: window.innerHeight,
        left: 100,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
```
It seems to do the same thing (scrolling to the container) but it just does it on load of the page and not when user scrolls. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, for those interested:
HTML:

```
<div class="cover" id="cover">
    ...
</div>

<div class="container" id="container">
    ...
</div>
```

Sass:

```
=full
    width: 100%
    height: 100%

* 
    box-sizing: border-box
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

.cover
    width: 100%
    height: 100vh
    float: left
    +transition(all, 1s, ease)
    overflow: hidden

    &.cover-close
        height: 0
```

JS:

```
var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
var cover = document.getElementsByClassName("cover")[0];

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollPosition >= 1) {
        cover.classList.add("cover-close");
    } else {
        cover.classList.remove("cover-close");
    }
});
```

I made a pen here: https://codepen.io/julien_sebag/pen/yLYWaRJ

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it's scrolling to the container but it's super slow (and didn't find how I could change the duration), and does not move after.

```
let cover = window.innerHeight
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: cover,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
})
```

If someone has a solution :)